# zookeeper high disk IO

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, io, apache-zookeeper, disk

Currently our 3 zookeeper instance running on EC2 suffering high disk IO (cpu wait 50% in top command).

Our Disk is 80G EBS which can get 240 4k IOPS

I iotop zookeeper Process shows Disk Write 900K/s

However I also tried sysdig which shows the transaction log that zookeeper writes with speed of 40KB/s only

```
sudo sysdig -pc -c topfiles_bytes
sysdig -c topfiles_bytes proc.name=java
```

And I confirm writing operation to zookeeper is about 300 operation/second, which will never reach 900K/s

does anyone experience such problem?

How can I leverage zookeeper's IO load?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing the similar issue.

Comment: We are facing same problem